# XCode Error Message: Ambiguous use of ’subscript'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

If I run my code in xcode simulator everything is fine, but once I try to run it on iphone I get this error message:

[image]

This is my code:

```
let myJsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
let myJson = myJsonArray[0] as AnyObject
let price_usd_str = myJson["price_usd"] as! String

price_usd = (NumberFormatter().number(from: price_usd_str)?.doubleValue)!
```

What exactly is wrong with it? Like I said it's fine in xcode alone I only get this error when wanting to play this on a phone.

Comment: Your `myJsonArray` is of `AnyObject` type, and it has no subscript defined. You'd need to cast it to `Array`

Comment: Please search. This has been [covered many times before](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+ambiguous+use+of+subscript).

Answer (score 0):

Your simulator uses an old swift runtime probably and runs fine, possibly because your iPhone is running latest iOS version than your Simulator. With new swift version, it's not able to infer the type that your myJsonArray is actually an array. 
Following change should fix it :

```
let myJsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as [[AnyObject: AnyObject]]
```

Even though it will fix the current error line, it will again complain about the next line, and it should be changed to following :

let myJson = myJsonArray[0] as [AnyObject: AnyObject]

Comment: It's **compile** time error, runtime version is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all a JSON dictionary is `[String:Any]` in Swift 3

Second of all, `AnyObject` is quite unspecific like *It's-an-object-but-I-have-no-idea-what-it-is*. When using key or index subscription the compiler **must** know the specific type of the subscripted object.

```
let myJsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: []) as! [[String:Any]]
let myJson = myJsonArray[0] // the compiler knows it's an array
let price_usd_str = myJson["price_usd"] as! String  // the compiler knows it's a dictionary
price_usd = (NumberFormatter().number(from: price_usd_str)?.doubleValue)!
```

Note: `.mutableContainers` is completely useless in Swift.